# Integral Representation for the Fox-H function on several variables

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration, mellin-transform

I have a problem that involves the H-function of several variables, and I have noticed that the implementation of such function when the number of variables are relatively high (greater than 5) must be done through some integral representation of the H-function.

My question is what is an integral representation for the Fox H function of several variables?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function):

The Mellin-Barnes integral representation is
$$
H_{p,q}^{\,m,n} \!\left[ z \left| \begin{matrix}
( a_1 , A_1 ) & ( a_2 , A_2 ) & \ldots & ( a_p , A_p ) \\
( b_1 , B_1 ) & ( b_2 , B_2 ) & \ldots & ( b_q , B_q ) \end{matrix} \right. \right]
= \\\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L
\frac
{(\prod_{j=1}^m\Gamma(b_j+B_js))(\prod_{j=1}^n\Gamma(1-a_j-A_js))}
{(\prod_{j=m+1}^q\Gamma(1-b_j-B_js))(\prod_{j=n+1}^p\Gamma(a_j+A_js))}
z^{-s} \, ds
$$
where $L$ is a certain contour separating the poles of the two factors in the numerator.